# In Laravel 5.3.30 artisan command not working

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-artisan

wills, I am in the app (aka project) directory.  The artisan file is in the directory that I am in.

Next...if I run the following command I get output (a list of the available commands):

> php artisan list

*But* if I run this command (purposefully leaving out a required argument), i don't get any error though i expect one:

> php artisan make:command

`artisan` seems to be unhappy in its configuration given that this purposefully incomplete command results in: no output.

**things i've tried**

- there is nothing in storage/logs/laravel.log
- the command `find -L ./ -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 php -l | grep "Errors parsing"` uncovers no files that have syntax errors
- `composer update`
- `composer install`
- `php artisan optimize`

Please offer solutions that will cause `php artisan bad:command` to complain as it should.

Comment: `Http` controllers are for http requests only. You should create an artisan command with a `signature` like `mycommand`, then add it to `Kernel.php` and launch with `php artisan mycommand`.

Comment: Right, and yet, make:command doesn't work.

Comment: It's hard to offer a solution, it's not a feature. It is a personal debug that needs to be used.

Comment: Is there a way to have the project and artisan rebuilt without losing code our configuration?

Comment: Is there a possibility to make a copy and play with it?

Comment: Would moving the project directory have caused it?

Comment: Yep. Something is done with the project that broken structure.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is:
use

```
php artisan migrate
```

instead of

```
php artinsa make:migration
```

When the above error happens, it is because the migrate has already been created.

**EDIT:** Removed portuguese translation of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First. `php artisan make:command Mycommand`

Second. `nano app/Console/Commands/Mycommand.php` and set `protected $signature = 'mycommand';`

Third. Code your logic in the file:

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->info('place your logic here');
}
```

Fourth. Add command to `app/Console/Kernel.php`

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\Mycommand::class
];
```

Check: `$ php artisan mycommand` outputs `place your logic here`.

Schedule: Edit the same `Kernel.php` file

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('mycommand')
             ->dailyAt('02:00')
             ->appendOutputTo('./mycommand.log')
             ->withoutOverlapping();;
}
```

It works as expected.

```
$ php artisan make:command           

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Not enough arguments (missing: "name").

$ php artisan --version              
 Laravel Framework version 5.3.30
```

Comment: The point is that something is wrong with artisan. I am purposefully leaving off the command name because it should throw an error. I only discovered this because using the desired command name argument resulted in nothing, so I removed it as a troubleshooting effort and found the artisan to be ill.  It should throw an error..what's wrong with it?

Comment: btw i vi not nano yo.

Comment: I've updated my answer. My artisan answers as expected. Post responses of yours.

Comment: Yeah that is the issue, there is no response. I can get the list and version but outside that it seems disabled.

Comment: I wish you a good debug day with vi and coffee. Try to remove requirements from composer.json and then add them one by one with `composer update` between. I suppose that one of them broke artisan.